# Dealing with a colleague with no experience

Tags: software-industry

I am a junior developer. I work for a startup where I am developing an android app. I use an API for my android app.

I have a colleague who says he has been in this company for 2 years. 
Whenever I use the API, it does not work. I asked him "why is API is not working?"

And In front of the boss he makes an excuse that I will look into it.

**Later when the boss is not in the office he comes to me ask why is API not working.** I believe that my senior colleague does not know much about the project.

Isn't his job to maintain the API? And he is asking me. He says that an android developer should also have knowledge on API development.

I do not get a very high salary (71.84 United States Dollar). And even with that salary, they expect me to work on something which is not in my job profile.

Boss agrees with my senior colleague.

Should I change my job?

Comment: They seem to be taking you for a ride... Look for another post, but when it comes to experience - explain what you were actually doing in positive terms...

Comment: @SolarMike Once I told my boss that it is not in my job profile. he started abusing me in front of other colleagues. That I am a fool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is not pleasant for sure, and you need a good strategy to win. Of course, you always have the back-up option to leave.

If you want to "fight", you need to prepare:

- be able explain clearly and shortly what you do;
- be able to explain clearly and shortly what are your expectations from the team, in order to be able to do your work;
- it might help to develop a closer relationship with your boss;

  - casually tell about your status sometimes;
  - try to talk positive, about what works about what you plan to do next;
  - just as a "side" note you add "I will have how to deal with that API which is still not working".

[**This**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136724/is-being-an-extrovert-a-necessary-condition-to-be-a-manager/136725#136725) applies not only to managers, but to anyone. The "noisier" the better.

Like anyone else, bosses do not like to hear about complaints, but about solutions and good news. Re-word what you say in order to emphasize what is good, but never forget to tell that you have problems.

You should maintain this attitude at all times, even during meetings.

Note: it is usually better to not refer to job descriptions and responsibilities. People usually feel threatened by that kind of talk.

Comment: I was very upset. I needed to talk to someone about my situation. @virolino

Comment: That is a mistake we all make. We should not say anything when we are upset, otherwise we have a high chance to do damage to ourselves.