# What should I do about a coworker that is slacking off and in turn, creating more work and stress for myself?

Tags: employer-relations, stress

EDIT: I had to edit this because I realized this situation is very specific and I am too paranoid thinking someone from work will see. Thank you kindly to those who read through my backstory and answered.

I don't have many friends in the corporate world, neither do I have any family members working office jobs; so needless to say it's hard to get any kind of advice.

I began working within a group of engineers who have all known each other for more than a decade; this is including my manager. It seems like my manager likes to take up for the slackers in the group, all because they have history together. When I have to work wiht one of the slackers, I am hesitant to go to her about the issues.

Comment: I agree the way she handled the issue with Sharon wasn't great, but it seems you didn't a great job explaining the issue either. Are there any other instances that make you think Kelly won't respond well to you reporting a work issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding a new job may involve waiting a long time. As well as getting the call the very same day. There is no exact science.

---

While you wait (and keep searching), you may try to improve the way you handle things. While they are a part of the problem, you have your share also.

You need to learn how to:

- accept tasks;
- estimate them;
- commit to them;
- deliver them;
- report issues to your boss;
- let others deal with their own problems.

---

When you are given tasks, you must analyze them and:

- evaluate their complexity;
- evaluate the time needed to implement them;
- provide a list of things which are mandatory for your success, and highlight the ones which are critical; also highlight the ones which you do not have at all;
- make it very clear how your work depends on somebody else's work (related to the previous topic);

Whenever you notice that you are going to encounter a **problem** or run into a **delay**, **discuss with your boss** about the causes of that. **Let her decide the priorities.** Do not make assumptions by yourself.

**Never accept** a task if you are certain you cannot do it - because of time, resources etc.

**Do everything in written.** If the discussion happened to be verbal, send an e-mail, describe the discussion, list the decisions, and ask for confirmation that you understood everything correctly.

---

Even though talking to a "bad" boss is quite unpleasant, you have to learn to do it. Even though you are not a boss yourself, reading [**this discussion**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/136725/98881) will help you. Most bosses have the need to be in the center of attention - even if it hurts the business. If you do not accept this, then accept to get hurt yourself. It's just life.

---

Do not worry about the work of your colleagues. Communicate with them about their deliverables which affect your work. If there is significant risk that you will not meet your deadline, **ask your boss for advice**, for deadline extension, or changing the list of priorities. **Let her assume the decision** of what will happen. **Make it in written**, as explained previously.

---

**Always have information ready** when reporting an issue. Show the list of tasks, the effort estimations, the estimated delays as a result of the issue.

If possible, also **have potential solutions**. **Bosses** tend to **like solutions**, rather than problems (like everybody else). Present the **solutions that you prefer**, so the boss will not choose a solution which you will not like.

---

You may end up actually **enjoying this job**, if you apply the rules above, before you have a chance to find a new job. The **opposite is also true**: you might have the same problems at the new job, if you do not learn how to handle things.

Good luck.